# Is there a name for somebody you’re jealous of?

Tags: compound-adjectives

I'm trying to describe King Saul's suicide out of fear of his rival David, of-whom-he-is-jealous. Is there a better way to describe this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a single-word name, but "the X of Saul's jealousy", where X is something along the lines of "focus", "target" or "object", might work?

Comment: If you're following the original, a better way to describe it would be "King Saul's suicide out of fear of capture and torture at the hands of the Philistines".

Comment: Star Trek Nemesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no word for *of-whom-he-is-jealous*. As Watercleave mentioned, *object of* is reasonable. There are other words, however, which do describe in one word what David was to Saul:

> - nemesis: a source of harm or ruin; an agent or act of retribution.
> - rival: one that equals or almost equals another in a particular respect.

Answer (score -1):

While it doesn't really have a biblical mien, you might consider *[the Joneses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_up_with_the_Joneses)* with whom you can never keep up.

> "Keeping up with the Joneses" is an idiom in many parts of the English-speaking world referring to the comparison to one's neighbor as a benchmark for social class or the accumulation of material goods. To fail to "keep up with the Joneses" is perceived as demonstrating socio-economic or cultural inferiority. [*Wikipedia*]